# Prove or disprove for all sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For all sets $A$, $B$, and $C$, if $C \setminus (A \cap B) = (A \cap C) \cup (B \cap C)$, then $C \subseteq B \cup$ A

Could you help me to prove it?

I tried to use a proof by contrapositive so making it in the following form:

if ($C \not\subseteq B \cup$ A) then $C \setminus (A \cap B) \neq (A \cap C) \cup (B \cap C)$

Then I tried to prove that:

(1) $C \setminus (A \cap B) \not\subseteq (A \cap C) \cup (B \cap C)$

(2) $(A \cap C) \cup (B \cap C) \not\subseteq  C \setminus (A \cap B)$

The first one seems feasible but as for the second one it is not clear to me how it could be proven?

Comment: What are your thoughts and/or attempted solution for this problem? Question that are not showing personal work and are just the statement of a problem aren't usually well received on this website

Comment: How are you sure that you shouldn't disprove this, i.e., how are you sure a counterexample doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\in C.$ If $x\in A\cap B$ we are done, otherwise $x\in C\setminus(A\cap B)=(A\cap C)\cup(B\cap C)$ and so $x\in A\cap C$ or $x\in B\cap C.$ Then $x\in A$ or $x\in B$ and it follows that $x\in A\cup B$ and hence $C\subseteq A\cup B.$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Approaching via [contraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition) seems easiest.

Suppose instead that $C\not\subseteq A\cup B$

That implies that there is some $x\in C$ such that...

...

...and so $C\setminus (A\cap B)\neq (A\cap C)\cup (B\cap C)$

---

The details in the middle of the proof are left for you to fill in.